# Update markers from Ajax Json array in google map when map is moved

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I would like my Google Map to update markers when the map is moved - using bounds_changed or idle - by submitting a new Ajax, removing existing markers and placing the new set.

So far I have the following two scripts:
- The first reads title, latitude and longitude from a JSON array and correctly places the markers in the map. But I have not been able to add the bounds_changed code correctly.
- The second script includes a bounds_changed trigger that loads a new set of markers into a div, but I don't know how to enter that array as the data for the markers (and update them).

If you can help me fix either of these two scripts so that I can get both things to work - read markers from JSON Array as in script 1 and update array when map is moved as in script 2 - I would be very grateful.

I have tried many variations and read all questions on SO that relate to the issue without luck. Totally stuck!

Script 1 - Getting markers from JSON Array:

```
<script>
jQuery(function($) {
    // Asynchronously Load the map API
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=SECRET&sensor=false&callback=initialize";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
});

function initialize() {
    var map;
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var mapOptions = {
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
    };
    ne_lng = -70.18087440625004;
    sw_lng = -92.10958534375004;
    ne_lat = 44.078852008513245;
    sw_lat = 28.9109895909681;

    // Display a map on the page
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
    map.setTilt(45);
    var latlngData = 0;

        // Info Window Content
        var infoWindowContent = [
            ['<div class="info_content">' +
            '<h3>London Eye</h3>' +
            '<p>The London Eye is a giant Ferris wheel situated on the banks of the River Thames. The entire structure is 135 metres (443 ft) tall and the wheel has a diameter of 120 metres (394 ft).</p>' + '</div>'],
            ['<div class="info_content">' +
            '<h3>Palace of Westminster</h3>' +
            '<p>The Palace of Westminster is the meeting place of the House of Commons and the House of Lords, the two houses of the Parliament of the United Kingdom. Commonly known as the Houses of Parliament after its tenants.</p>' +
            '</div>']
        ];

        // Display multiple markers on a map, same info for everyone, just an example
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;

        // Loop through our array of markers & place each one on the map, fetching avg_gps_latitude,   avg_gps_longitude from latlngData, received from ajax call ( but it dodn't work)
        loadLocations().done(function (latlngData) {


            for (i = 0; i < latlngData.length; i++) {
                var position = new google.maps.LatLng(latlngData[i].latitude, latlngData[i].longitude);
                bounds.extend(position);
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: position,
                    map: map,
                    title: latlngData[i].ssid
                });

                // Allow each marker to have an info window
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
                    return function () {
                        infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent[0][0]);
                        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                    }
                })(marker, i));

                // Automatically center the map fitting all markers on the screen
                map.fitBounds(bounds);
            }

          });


        // Override our map zoom level once our fitBounds function runs (Make sure it only runs once)
        var boundsListener = google.maps.event.addListener((map), 'bounds_changed', function (event) {
            this.setZoom(6);
            google.maps.event.removeListener(boundsListener);
        });
    }


    function loadLocations()
    {
        return $.ajax({
              type:'POST',
              url: 'includes/newjson.php',
              dataType: 'json',
              data:{
                a: ne_lat,
                b: ne_lng,
                c: sw_lat,
                d: sw_lng
      },
      async: true,
      //cache: false,
      success: function(result){
          console.log("successx");
          console.log(result);
          var jsonStr = JSON.stringify(result);
          $('#results').html(jsonStr);
          // $('#results').html(result);
           // initialize();
          },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
          alert(xhr.status);
          alert(thrownError);
        }
  });
  }

  //  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);


</script>
```

Script 2 - Updates array in #result with JSON Array when map is moved but not passed on to Google Maps markers (original array is entered as PHP variable in script):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {
    // Asynchronously Load the map API
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=SECRET&sensor=false&callback=initialize";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
});

function initialize() {
    var map;
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var mapOptions = {
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
    };

    // Display a map on the page
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
    map.setTilt(45);

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function(){
        // alert(this.getBounds());
    ne_lng = map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lng();
    sw_lng = map.getBounds().getSouthWest().lng();
    ne_lat = map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lat();
    sw_lat = map.getBounds().getSouthWest().lat();
    console.log(ne_lng);
    console.log(sw_lng);
    console.log(ne_lat);
    console.log(sw_lat);

    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: 'includes/mapQuery.php',
        data:{
          a: ne_lat,
          b: ne_lng,
          c: sw_lat,
          d: sw_lng
},
async: true,
cache: false,
        success: function(result){
            console.log("success");
            $('#results').html(result);
            // newmarkers = result;
            // console.log(newmarkers);
        } // End of success function of ajax form
    }); // End of ajax call

    });

    // Multiple Markers
    var markers =
    <?php
        echo str_replace('"', "'", json_encode($maparray, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK));
    ?>
    ;

    // Info Window Content
    var infoWindowContent = [
        ['<div class="info_content">' +
        '<h3>London Eye</h3>' +
        '<p>The London Eye is a giant Ferris wheel situated on the banks of the River Thames. The entire structure is 135 metres (443 ft) tall and the wheel has a diameter of 120 metres (394 ft).</p>' +        '</div>'],
        ['<div class="info_content">' +
        '<h3>Palace of Westminster</h3>' +
        '<p>The Palace of Westminster is the meeting place of the House of Commons and the House of Lords, the two houses of the Parliament of the United Kingdom. Commonly known as the Houses of Parliament after its tenants.</p>' +
        '</div>']
    ];

    // Display multiple markers on a map
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;

    // Loop through our array of markers & place each one on the map
    for( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
        var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
        bounds.extend(position);
        var iconBase = 'img/icons/';
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: position,
            map: map,
            icon: iconBase + 'student-icon.png',
            title: markers[i][0]
        });

        // Allow each marker to have an info window
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
                infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent[i][0]);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));

        // Automatically center the map fitting all markers on the screen
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }

    // Override our map zoom level once our fitBounds function runs (Make sure it only runs once)
    var boundsListener = google.maps.event.addListener((map), 'bounds_changed', function(event) {
        this.setZoom(6);
        google.maps.event.removeListener(boundsListener);
    });



}</script>
```

Comment: Just received a downvote on this question which apparently suggests "no research effort" or unclearly stated question. For the first part that's definitely not the case: I have spent two days to come up with the two separate solutions I have posted and consulted EVERY SINGLE SO post (and elsewhere as well) that were even tangentially related. The problem is not lack of research (but probably lack of knowledge on my part). As for the question being vague, I chose to pose it as I did rather than post any of my MANY failed attempts because I had no confidence they were on right track.

Comment: Hi mads Stenbjerre, i have same issue as you mention above . So can u  please post answer if you resolved.I will be thankfull to you.Thanks.

Comment: Hi Rax, See my final code below. Good luck!

Comment: @MadsStenbjerre hello, I tried the run your codem because what I wanted is exactly like yours. But having couldn't achieve it could please check it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54759041/display-new-markers-when-map-bound-changed-and-clear-old-marker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

````
    If I understand correctly, there are two thing you want to achieve here. 

    1. when initialize the map, get json from server and add makers on it.
    2. when bounds changes, get json and redraws all the maps.

    You are very close, I would suggest you to reorganize your code.

    1. you need a global array of marks, so you can remove makers from map for redrawing.

    ```
    // set globals
    var makers = []
    // clear markers
    function clearMaker (markers) {
      markers.map(m => {m.setmap(null)})
    }
    ```

    2. seperate drawMarkers function
    ```
    // drawMarkers
    function drawMarkers(markerJson, markers, map, infowindow) {
      clearMarkers(markers);
      // your draw marker code
    }
    ```

    3. Your loadLocation

    ```
    /*search location based on geoparams
    geoparam: {
                 a: ne_lat,
                 b: ne_lng,
                 c: sw_lat,
                 d: sw_lng
    }
    */

    function loadLocations(geoparam)
    {
            return $.ajax({
                  type:'POST',
                  url: 'includes/newjson.php',
                  dataType: 'json',
                  data: geoparam
            })
      }
    ```
You can call loadLocation functions when initilize and bounds_changed and it returns a promise.

```
loadLocation(geoparams).then((data) => {
  drawMarkers(data, markers, map, inforwindow);
}).catch(err => { console.log(error)});
```
````

Comment: Thank you, Jerry. You have understood my goals correctly. I will be able to test in a few hours. Meanwhile could you please illustrate the code needed for "call loadLocation functions when initilize and bounds_changed"?

Comment: in ```function initialize() { }``` You have you default ne_lng, sw_lng, ne_lat, sw_lat. after you initilize map you just call loadLocation with your default geoparams. Then in your bounds_change event handler ```google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {})```, after you get new geoparams call loadLocation with new params.

Comment: I have tried to implement the changes but cannot get them to work. The current code is in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bqm6odog/  (I have removed the api key for Google Maps.)

Comment: Just to clarify: No map is drawn and I get "Uncaught reference error: google is not defined" referring to this part of the code:   google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
  loadLocation(geoparams).then((data) => {
    drawMarkers(data, markers, map, inforwindow);
  }).catch(err => { console.log(error)});
});

Comment: Because your ajax method dit not work, I have not tested the drawMarks function. But I fix some bugs for you. https://jsfiddle.net/bqm6odog/4/ 1. the map container must have a fixed height 2. you'd better use idle for you bounds change event.

Comment: Thanks Jerry. Big help!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution that worked for me. The result can be seen [here](http://stenbjerre.com/winwood/map.php).

JSON data comes from this php-file that is updated whenever the map is moved:

```
include("conn.php");
$ne_lat = $_POST['a'];
$ne_lon = $_POST['b'];
$sw_lat = $_POST['c'];
$sw_lon = $_POST['d'];

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT schoolname, latitude, longitude, total_students, act_composite_25, schoolid, (sat_critread_25+sat_math_25) as sat, (100 * admissions_total/applicants_total) as admrate, degree_bachelor, degree_masters, url, city, usstate, tuition_outstate, tuition_instate FROM usschools WHERE
(CASE WHEN $ne_lat < $sw_lat
        THEN latitude BETWEEN $ne_lat AND $sw_lat
        ELSE latitude BETWEEN $sw_lat AND $ne_lat
END)
AND
(CASE WHEN $ne_lon < $sw_lon
        THEN longitude BETWEEN $ne_lon AND $sw_lon
        ELSE longitude BETWEEN $sw_lon AND $ne_lon
END) and degree_bachelor = 1 order by act_composite_25 desc limit 20");
  if (!$result) {
    printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
    exit();
}

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $data[] = $row;
  }
```

And the map is generated and markers updated like this:

```
    <script>
    jQuery(function($) {
        // Asynchronously Load the map API
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYKEY&sensor=false&callback=initialize";
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    });

        ne_lng = -70.18087440625004;
        sw_lng = -92.10958534375004;
        ne_lat = 44.078852008513245;
        sw_lat = 28.9109895909681;

        function initialize() {
          var markers;
          var map;
          var markers1 = [];


            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(46.35960484925907, -81.34113061749997),
    new google.maps.LatLng(39.41643540717689, -70.37677514874997)
);
            var mapOptions = {
                mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
            };

        // Display a map on the page
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
        map.setTilt(45);
        var latlngData = 0;


        var boundsListener = google.maps.event.addListener((map), 'bounds_changed', function (event) {
            this.setZoom(6);
            google.maps.event.removeListener(boundsListener);
        });
// Automatically center the map fitting all markers on the screen
map.fitBounds(bounds);

// would be great if a margin could be added to prevent schools on edges from loading without marker
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function() {
    ne_lng = map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lng()-0.01;
    sw_lng = map.getBounds().getSouthWest().lng()+0.01;
    ne_lat = map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lat()-0.01;
    sw_lat = map.getBounds().getSouthWest().lat()+0.01;
    console.log(ne_lng);
    console.log(sw_lng);
    console.log(ne_lat);
    console.log(sw_lat);

      function loadLocations()
        {
          $("#results").empty();
            return $.ajax({
                  type:'POST',
                  url: 'includes/newjson.php',
                  dataType: 'json',
                  data:{
                    a: ne_lat,
                    b: ne_lng,
                    c: sw_lat,
                    d: sw_lng
          },
          async: true,
          success: function(result){
              console.log("ajax");
              console.log(result);

              var len = result.length;
            for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
                var id = result[i].schoolid;
                var name = result[i].schoolname;
                var students = (result[i].total_students).toLocaleString();
                var act = result[i].act_composite_25;
                var sat = result[i].sat;
                var acceptancerate = (result[i].admrate).toFixed(1);
                var degree_bachelor = result[i].degree_bachelor;
                var degree_masters = result[i].degree_masters;
                var url = result[i].url;
                var city = result[i].city;
                var usstate = result[i].usstate;
                var tuition_outstate = (result[i].tuition_outstate).toLocaleString();
                var tuition_instate = (result[i].tuition_instate).toLocaleString();
                var tr_str = "<div class='resultBox'>" +
                    "<div class='resultImg'><span class='helper'></span><object data='img/schools/logo" + id + ".png' type='image/png' class='resultLogo'><img src='img/schools/logo.png' class='resultLogo'></object></div>" +
                    "<div class='resultColumn1'><div class='resultName'>" + name + "</div>" +
                    "<div class='resultBachelor" + degree_bachelor + "'></div>" +
                    "<div class='resultMasters" + degree_masters + "'></div>" +
                    "<div class='resultAddress'>" + city + ", " + usstate + "</div>" +
                    "<div class='resultStudents'>Students: " + students + "</div>" +
                    "<div class='resultTuition'>Tuition: $" + tuition_outstate + "/$" + tuition_instate + "</div></div>" +
                    "<div class='resultColumn2'><div class='resultAct'><div class='testLabel'><img src='img/act.png' class='tests'></div><div class='testScore act'>" + act + "</div></div>" +
                    "<div class='resultSat'><div class='testLabel'><img src='img/sat.png' class='tests'></div><div class='testScore sat'>" + sat + "</div></div><div class='testLegend'>Required score</div>" +
                    "<div class='resultAcceptRate'><div class='acceptBar' style='height:"+acceptancerate+"%'></div><div class='acceptLabel' style='bottom:"+acceptancerate+"%'>" + acceptancerate + "%</div></div><div class='acceptLegend'>Accepted</div></div>" +
                    "<div class='resultColumn3'><div class='resultSaveSchool'><a href='saveSchool?id=" + id + "' target='_new' class='btn btn-result btn-save'>Save</a></div>" +
                    "<div class='resultMore'><a href='https://" + url + "' target='_new' class='btn btn-result btn-school-url'>Website</a></div></div>" +
                    "</div>";

                $("#results").append(tr_str);
            }
              },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
              alert(xhr.status);
              alert(thrownError);
            }
      });
      }

                  // Loop through our array of markers & place each one on the map, fetching avg_gps_latitude,   avg_gps_longitude from latlngData, received from ajax call ( but it dodn't work)
                  loadLocations().done(function (latlngData) {

                    for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {
                            markers1[i].setMap(null);
                            }
                            markers1 = [];
                            markers = [];
                            markers = loadLocations();

                      for (i = 0; i < latlngData.length; i++) {
                        //var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker;
                        var letter = String.fromCharCode("A".charCodeAt(0) + i - 1);
                        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;
                              var infoWindowContent = '<div class="info_content">' +
                              '<p class="infoWindowName">'+' '+latlngData[i].schoolname+'</p></div>';
                          var tooltip = '';
                          var position = new google.maps.LatLng(latlngData[i].latitude, latlngData[i].longitude);
                          bounds.extend(position);
                          var iconBase = 'img/icons/';
                          var labeltext = latlngData[i].schoolname;
                          marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                              position: position,
                              map: map,
                              label: {
                                color: '#111',
                                text: labeltext,
                                fontSize: '12px'
                          },
                              icon: iconBase + 'marker_black.png'
                              //title: tooltip
                          });
                          markers1.push(marker);

                          // Allow each marker to have an info window
                          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, infoWindowContent) {
                              return function () {
                                  infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent);
                                  infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                              }
                          })(marker, infoWindowContent));
                          // Automatically center the map fitting all markers on the screen
                          //map.fitBounds(bounds);
                      }
                      console.log("loadLocations");
                    });
});
}
</script>
```